# Get the variable using the data stored in .data() in javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have an array object that has values stored in `.data()`.

The code is:

```
cell[0] = paper.rect(60, 60, 60, 60).attr({stroke: 'black'}).data('x', 1).data('y',2);
```

I want to know is if it is possible to get the variable by using the values stored in .data(). If so, please tell how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using rapahel js

Comment: `paper.data('x')` doesn't do it?

Comment: or `cell[0].data('x')`

Comment: What do you mean by "get the variable using the value"? Do you mean "set a variable to the value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can retrieve the data just by calling `data('yourValue')` on your stored element.
e.g.:

```
cell[0].data('y')
```

Just call the cell with data and the name of your stored value.

See example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/269rhbc7/1/